# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'use

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run SQL on phpmyadmin but gettin tis error, and can't find what's wrong in it.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'use android_api /** Selecting Database **/

My code below:

```
create database android_api /** Creating Database **/ 
use android_api /** Selecting Database **/

create table users(
id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
name varchar(50) not null,
email varchar(100) not null unique,
encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
salt varchar(10) not null,
created_at datetime,
updated_at datetime null
); /** Creating Users Table **/
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **use android_api** . You don't need to have that.
`USE` statement is only use for each time you begin a `mysql` session.

Assume android_api have created and you have log out `mysql`. When you log in again, then only you need to use `USE` statement.

**Edit**

Need a space between users and (

```
create table users (
```

Comment: Still getting an error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'create table users(
   id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id var' at line 2

Comment: answer edited..